# AWS Code Deploy failing scripts (permissions)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I am attempting to run a few scripts while deploying using AWS Code Deploy.Script run from user - does not work. Example:

I have:

```
/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/XXXXX/d-XXXXX# ls -al

drwxr-xr-x 4 root root      4096 Apr 13 16:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root      4096 Apr 13 16:08 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 102671590 Apr 13 16:02 bundle.tar
drwx------ 5 root root      4096 Apr 11 19:25 deployment-archive
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      4096 Apr 13 16:02 logs
```

Should have:

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 Apr  5 11:22 deployment-archive
```

My appsec:

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /home/test/app
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: bin/delete.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
  AfterInstall:
    - location: bin/privileges.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: bin/start.sh
      timeout: 120
      runas: test
```

I got error:

```
Script - bin/start.sh [stderr]bash: /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/06b0fsbb-69bf-4863-bb73-b1f6efb86075/d-LV0Z7LOIN/deployment-archive/bin/start.sh: Permission denied
Script at specified location: bin/start.sh run as user test failed with exit code 126
```

And this user does not have access to this directory

```
/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/06b0fsbb-69bf-4863-bb73-b1f6efb86075/d-LV0Z7LOIN/deployment-archive
```

I don't know what the problem is. Any advice?